# Is that a sabotage by my user name, or it's a systematic error?

Tags: support

Few minutes ago, I noticed that there seems to be a long edition by my user name which has done for the following answer of @Medi1Saif:

https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1766/revisions

But, I have not done this long edition at all. I wonder if it is a kind of sabotage or it is solely related to a systematic error?

Comment: This looks like a copy-paste problem to me; how sure are you that it wasn't just a case of having two tabs open and copying from one, editing it, and accidentally pasting it into the other? Or having the wrong post loaded into your clipboard from a previous edit, and pasting that instead of whatever you meant to paste?

Comment: Uh-huh, of course I am not sure about it, but perhaps you are right. I'll check it. Thanks for paying attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my perspective I must say that what goldPseudo said seems to me very plausible. As you seem to have been editing two different answers of mine and there your trouble came from ;)

I'd say it was a copy-paste issue!

That happen to me when i have been interrupted or my attention for a few minutes has been directed to a different thing.